# browserify modules and notation

Tags: javascript, browserify

Suppose I have a MyViewModel like this:

```
// MyViewModel.js module
function MyViewModel() { 
};

exports.MyViewModel = MyViewModel;
```

And main.js using it:

```
// main.js 
var MyViewModel = require('./MyViewModel');
var vm = new MyViewModel.MyViewModel(); // akward
```

it's weird to have `new MyViewModel.MyViewModel()`.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself:

```
// MyViewModel.js module
module.exports = function MyViewModel() { 
};
```